# In Python lxml.etree why the apostrophe is not automatically escaped as other characters?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I was wondering why the apostrophe is not automatically escaped as other characters?

For example, at the moment of create the `xml` file:

`<` is transformed to `&lt;` and `>` is transformed to `&gt;`, but `'` is not transformed to `&apos;`. Is there an special reason for that?

My solution at this moment is to use `tostring()` to save the file and after that apply a replace, nevertheless, I think is a bad and dirty solution, because I need to add the XML's header `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` with hardcoding. I have the next code:

```
element = Element('Root')

element.set('Version', '1.0')
element.set('test0', a['zero']) # the content is '<'
element.set('test1', a['one']) # the content is '>'
element.set('test2', a['two']) # the content is '&'
element.set('test3',  a['three']) # the content is '"'

# the content is O'Reilly, here is my problem
element.set('test4', a['four'])

tree = ElementTree(element)
xmlfile = open('xmlfile.xml', 'wb+')
tree.write(xmlfile, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
xmlfile.close()
```

**EDIT:**

I received this answer in the `lxml` mailing list:

Because it's not needed?
See https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml for a similar discussion.

However I am not pretty convinced about this answer.

Comment: Read more about the [rules of escaping the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents).